# Handle Google API Response

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the comments from a YouTube video and do some further work with them. I started with the implementation example from the docs for "CommentThreads: list" and continued from there on.

Using a main function I want to call the `execute` function and use the response it should return. It should look kinda like the following:

```
function execute() {
  return gapi.client.youtube.commentThreads.list({
    "part": [
      "snippet"
    ],
    "fields":[
      "items/snippet/topLevelComment/snippet(authorDisplayName,authorProfileImageUrl,publishedAt,textDisplay)"
    ],
    "videoId": "XXXXX"
  }).then(function(response) {
              console.log(response.result);
            },
            function(err) { 
              console.error("Execute error", err); 
            });
}

function main(){
  let response = execute();
  console.log(response);
}
```

And the output in the console looks like this:

```
{
    "Ca": 2,
    "yb": null,
    "Yj": null,
    "Sn": null,
    "KB": false,
    "xw": false
}
```

Another way I tried to solve this is to not return `gapi.client.youtube.commentThreads.list` but the response in the successful promise function like so:

```
function execute() {
  gapi.client.youtube.commentThreads.list({
    "part": [
      "snippet"
    ],
    "fields":[
      "items/snippet/topLevelComment/snippet(authorDisplayName,authorProfileImageUrl,publishedAt,textDisplay)"
    ],
    "videoId": "XXXXX"
  }).then(function(response) {
              console.log(response.result);
              return reponse.result;
            },
            function(err) { 
              console.error("Execute error", err); 
            });
}
```

But here I only get an `undefined`.

I am just learning JavaScript and the use of the API.

EDIT:
I should also add that the `console.log(response.result);` in the execute function does print the information I want. But as soon as I return it and want to use it in the `main()` function it changes.

Comment: It looks like your code ends up in the Promise `onFulfilled` branch. You mention that output of `console.log(response.result)` is `undefined`. What is the output of `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))`?

Comment: @Miro
The `console.log(response.result);` in the `execute()` function does output the right information that I need. The problem I have is returning that json so that I can do stuff with it in another function.
So with that, I don't know if that is what you meant but when doing it like that in the main I still get an undefined:
```
function raffle(){
  let response = execute();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
}
```

Comment: I was suggesting that you use `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` directly inside `onFulfilled` of `then` (e.g. `.then(function(response) {console.log(JSON.stringify(response));}`) and share a result.

Comment: `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` gives the following output. I cut it short as the output is very long.

`{"result":{"items":[{"snippet":{"topLevelComment":{"snippet":{"textDisplay":"Hab mir euer Video angesehen,hat mir sehr gut gefallen. ....`

As I noted in the `onFullfilled` branch I do have the data that I want to return. The issue is when I return that value that I get something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to that when using the gapi that it returns a promise that I want to return. Promised are not evaluated immediately which means that it continues to execute the following functions, returning a value that has no response yet.

I solved the issue by using the async/await functionality to work with promises, which seemed to be more understandable and elegant in my eyes. I also changed some variables to constants as they did not need to be non-constants. My result looks like the following:

```
await function execute() {
  let response = await gapi.client.youtube.commentThreads.list({
    "part": [
      "snippet"
    ],
    "fields":[
      "items/snippet/topLevelComment/snippet(authorDisplayName,authorProfileImageUrl,publishedAt,textDisplay)"
    ],
    "videoId": "XXXXX"
  });
  
  return response.result;
}

async function main(){
  let response = await execute();
  console.log(response);
}
```

The reason why we also have to use async and await in the `main()` function is that by definition async functions always return promises.

To learn more about async/await I found this article whose explanation I liked: https://javascript.info/async-await

They also have an article about promises: https://javascript.info/promise-basics